# Проблема при отправке файлов aigram 3

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не могу разобраться что происходит. По какой то причине бот периодически отказывается отправлять файлы по запросу.

```
        f = await nv(message, bot)
        doc = str(f)
        out = FSInputFile(doc)
        await message.answer_document(out)
```

понимаю, что можно сократить число строк, так написал просто пока в ходе экспериментов.

Дак вот, бот совершенно спокойно может несколько раз подряд отправить нужный файл, а потом при очередной попытке выдать вот такую портянку. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина

```
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=772884910 is not handled. Duration 64375 ms by bot id=5675500369
ERROR:aiogram.event:Cause exception while process update id=772884910 by bot id=5675500369
TelegramNetworkError: ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 145, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 559, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 898, in start
    message, payload = await protocol.read()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 616, in read
    await self._waiter
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 277, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 135, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/error.py", line 24, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/middlewares/user_context.py", line 23, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/fsm/middleware.py", line 39, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 212, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 244, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 129, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 125, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/router.py", line 138, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py", line 212, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/event/handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/main.py", line 50, in handle_document
    await message.answer_document(out)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/methods/base.py", line 85, in emit
    return await bot(self)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 348, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 168, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "/home/tgbot/PycharmProjects/BuxHelper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 152, in make_request
    raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected
```

Comment: Проблема в `TelegramNetworkError`, если перевести, что получим? Поясню, бот не может подключиться к серверу Telegram из-за  потери соединения. Причин может быть масса: сетевые проблемы, временная недоступность самого сервера Telegram, а возможно по причине ограничения по времени ввода\вывода (`timeout`) запроса(возможно стоит добавить задержку, если что-то часто отправляете). Как вариант решения - обрабатывайте ошибку через `try\except` и посылайте файл повторно, до тех пор пока не отправится.